# replace function not working in regards of back slash

Tags: javascript, node.js

below is my code code to replace black slash

```
var c = ';\&"%';
c = c.replace(/;/g,"w").replace(/\\/g,"e").replace(/&/g," and ").replace(/"/g,"e").replace(/%/g,"r");
```

expected output : we and rt

orignal output : w and rt

Answer (score 0):

```
> var c = ';\&"%';
> c
';&"%'
```

Backslashes that aren’t part of recognized escapes don’t do anything. Escape the backslash.

```
var c = ';\\&"%';
```